Why is off_t signed?
On my journey to create a 16 EiB sized file,
I encountered the following issue:
POSIX defines files to have their size represented using type off_t,
and that "blkcnt_t and off_t shall be signed integer types."
According to unistd.h, _POSIX_V7_LP64_OFF64 requires 64-bit off_t types, while _POSIX_V7_LPBIG_OFFBIG allows for larger ones:

_POSIX_V7_LP64_OFF64
The implementation provides a C-language compilation environment with 32-bit int
and 64-bit long, pointer, and off_t types.
_POSIX_V7_LPBIG_OFFBIG
The implementation provides a C-language compilation environment with an int type using at least 32 bits and long, pointer, and off_t types using at least 64 bits.

The only reason for off_t being signed is its use in lseek
and fseek, where the formal argument offset can be used to specify the file offset relative to some other value,
if whence is set to either SEEK_CUR or SEEK_END.
To me, this seems odd, as I can't imagine this case to be worth wasting half of the usable range for the file size,
since any code relying on this feature could easily be rewritten to request the current absolute offset, add/subtract the relative offset and then seek to this calculated value.
Are there any other reasons for POSIX to specify off_t to be a signed type?
UPDATE
I noticed that the UNIX PROGRAMMER’S MANUAL (TYPES ( 5 ), Seventh Edition, Volume 1
January, 1979) defined off_t to be a long:

typedef long off_t;

Though, when digging further, I found FSEEK ( 3S ) to reveal it being used as signed long as well:
fseek(stream, offset, ptrname)
FILE *stream;
long offset;


Fseek sets the position of the next input or output operation on the stream. The new position is at the
signed distance offset bytes from the beginning, the current position, or the end of the file, according as
ptrname has the value 0, 1, or 2.


As you discovered, off_t has been around for a long time, and has always (as far as I’m aware) been signed. Since that’s “baked in”, POSIX can’t change it.
There are other uses for off_t in V7 which support its signedness; in particular, it’s used for difference calculations where results can be negative.
Present-day uses of off_t aren’t limited to lseek and co.’s arguments; it’s also used for lseek’s return value, where a negative value is used to indicate an error (which also goes back to V7).

The backward compatibility issue is significant, but it strikes me as “begging the question” — it just kicks the can down the road, leaving us to ask why off_t was initially defined to be signed.  (Of course, your second paragraph addresses that.)       I’m not sure your third paragraph really presents a good reason — it would be possible to say that off_t is unsigned, and lseek returns (off_t)-1 on error.  (Then again, if 18446744073709551614 was a valid off_t and 18446744073709551615 wasn’t, that might cause problems.)

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica': So here's the actual story on that. (size_t)-1 through (size_t)-4095 or so are reserved for error codes (exact lower bound varies; a few systems were found with a really large one). In usermode, lseek returns -1 for error; however from kernel itself it returns -errno, whatever it is. The constraining API isn't lseek though; it's mmap.

The answer to most of these sorts of questions is backwards compatibility. Early (pre-standard) versions of C didn't have a concept of unsigned types (while most of the early language was stabilized by '73, unsigned didn't come into existence until '77).
When there's no such thing as unsigned anyway, and you can save an (at the time, very expensive) extra system call by allowing current-position-relative and end-relative seeks with the negative values that would go otherwise unused, you're going to do it (a single relative seek system call is half the cost of a tell system call, computing the new absolute offset, followed by seek system call).
When long and unsigned came around, the seek interfaces were already established by convention/documentation (even if no official standards body had endorsed them). While it made sense to make use of the new long type to handle larger files, using unsigned would break existing, valid, and performant uses of fseek. So they didn't. Even today, halving the number of system calls is worth something (the context switch, including flush of the TLB, costs quite a bit), and back then they were issued much less efficiently, on slower machines; every cycle counted.
fseek's utility when it comes to end-relative seeks of binary files in the standard is... questionable, but it worked on enough systems that it would have been painful to insist that end-relative seeks required you to compute the file size (a thing that it wasn't always obvious how to do with anything but fseek) every time, rather than just passing the offset from the end you wanted to seek to.

In principle, seeking with a separate fstat can also have race conditions if the file size changes (but in practice, SEEK_END with negative offset probably does not fix those problems anyway - the filesystem is endemically racy and there's usually nothing you can do about it).

I found it more sane to use negative offsets with current-relative seeks.

Note that there's no tell() system call. To return the current offset from the start, you call lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR). Note the system call is lseek(), not fseek() which is a stdio function like ftell() that work with FILE objects (an abstraction in the libc that implements buffering, which in the end helps saving system calls).

@StéphaneChazelas: I avoided code formatting when referring to tell, precisely to avoid getting bogged down in the distinction between stdio calls and system calls in a scenario where they (usually) have 1-1 equivalence. I only referred to fseek at all because the OP did, and again, it's usually 1-1 with system calls (it actually leads to a couple of system calls if there is buffered data to be written, since it guarantees an fflush in that case).
